# How to call Cloud Code Function(Parse) in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I don't know which parameters to pass into this Cloud Code Function(parse.com)

```
Parse.Cloud.define('stripe_card_create', function(req, res) {
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
method: 'POST',
headers: stripe_headers,
url: environment.stripe.api_url + '/customers/' + req.params.customer_id + '/sources',
params: {
  source: req.params.token_id
},
success: function(card) {
  res.success(card.data);
},
error: function(err) {
  res.error(err.text);
    }
  })
});
```

These were supposed to be called

req.customer_id (Required) The customer id

req.token_id (Required) The tokenized card
But i receive an error when i call with this function

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("stripe_card_create", withParameters: ["req.params.customer_id":"req.params.token_id"])
```

This is the error

```
   [Error]: {
      "error": {
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "message": "No such customer: undefined",
        "param": "customer"
      }
    }
     (Code: 141, Version: 1.7.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Cloud function, `req.params.customer_id` means this in English:

From the `req` in the `function(req, res)`, grab the `params`. From the `params` property, grab the key named `customer_id`. When you call the function from your Swift code, the dictionary key you pass will be a property of `params`.

Your cloud code expects a key `customer_id`, not `req.params.customer_id`. You want to do this:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("stripe_card_create", withParameters: ["customer_id": "\(whatever the id is you need to pass)"], block: nil)
```

The value for the key you're passing in the Dictionary is very oddly named as well. Either that is a mistake from the same vein or you should really rename it to something nicer.

Comment: Is it safe to pass a session token through cloud code parameters? How can you set headers?